# ASP.NET 3.5 Stateless Session Managment and connection pooling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, universe

I am designing an ASP.NET (3.5) web application that connects to a Rocket Software UniVerse database. I am in the planning stages right now and need some help in being pointed in the right direction. I am brand new to ASP and C#.

I am shooting for a RESTful design and a MVC pattern. Rocket provides a .NET library called UniObjects.NET which handles everything for connecting and retrieving information from the database.

What would be the best way to in general to log my users into the database, then use that session via connection pooling? I see that in 3.5 there is the ASP.NET Routing Infrastructure and that looks promising am I in the right direction on this?

Also does C# support decorators like Python and Java?

Answer (score 1):

For your application I highly recommend taking a look at the official ASP.NET MVC framework (www.asp.net/mvc). The traditional ASP.NET (which is called WebForms) is clunky when it comes to true separation of concerns, dependency injection, unit testing etc. A very good starting point is:

- [Free End-to-End tutorial EBook "NerdDinner"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) - walks you through a complete application with ASP.NET MVC

As for connecting to a database: If your Database has an ADO.NET Provider you should learn the basics of accessing data via ADO.NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719474.aspx)

It is also recommended to use some kind of OR Mapper like NHibernate or Microsoft Entity Framework for converting relational data to the object-oriented world.

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping]
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate]
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx]

As this is a very broad topic, please feel free to follow up with any questions you might have. I suggest starting with the NerdDinner Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked into ADO.NET and LINQ to SQL. They are possible, however UniVerse is not a native relational database. Excellent sources of information though and the Nerd Dinner tutorial is excellent as well.